# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null when using Locomotive Scroll with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, locomotive-scroll

I am trying to use locomotive scroll but but I get an error

[image]

I try to use react-locomotive-scroll but get the same error

My `_app.tsx` looks like this

[image]

Where is my mistake? I try to put inside layout component which wraps the entire page, but it didn't work too

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { ThemeProvider, Global } from "@emotion/react";
import { theme } from "../src/common/theme";
import { globalStyles } from "../src/styles/global";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import "locomotive-scroll/dist/locomotive-scroll.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    let scroll;
    import("locomotive-scroll").then((locomotiveModule) => {
      scroll = new locomotiveModule.default({
        el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
        smooth: true,
        smoothMobile: false,
        resetNativeScroll: true,
      });
    });

    // `useEffect`'s cleanup phase
    return () => scroll.destroy();
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Global styles={globalStyles(theme)} />
      <Component {...pageProps} data-scroll-container />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

I also use `next-transpile-modules`

```
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["gsap", "locomotive-scroll"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because no element with the `data-scroll-container` attribute is present on the DOM.

Setting `data-scroll-container` in `Component` doesn't actually add the attribute to any element. `Component` is a React component, not an HTML element.

You should add a new element that wraps `Component` and set the attribute on it instead.

```js
<div data-scroll-container>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was doing this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ;(async () => {
    try {
      const LocomotiveScroll = (await import('locomotive-scroll')).default
      const dataScrollContainer = document.querySelector(
        '[data-scroll-container]',
      )

      if (!dataScrollContainer) {
        console.warn(
          'locomotive-scroll: [data-scroll-container] dataset was not found. You likely forgot to add it which will prevent Locomotive Scroll to work.',
        )
      }

      window.locomotive = new LocomotiveScroll({
        el: dataScrollContainer ?? undefined,
        smooth: true,
      })
    } catch (error) {}
  })()

  return () => {
    window.locomotive?.destroy()
  }
}, [])
```

And have a div with `data-scroll-container` somewhere. So instead of directly loading it, do it async.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a simpler option that worked for me:

```js
export default function Component() {

  const { scroll } = useLocomotiveScroll()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scroll) {
      scroll.on('scroll', onScroll);
    }
    // remove event on unmount to prevent a memory leak with the cleanup
    return () => {
      if (scroll) {
        scroll.destroy('scroll', onScroll);
      }
    }
  }, [scroll]);

};
```

Just provide the locomotive scroll as a dependency to t useEffect.

```js
useEffect(() => {...}, [scroll]) // See scroll used as a dependency here
```

Problem solved.